# Fortran pointer and their memory usage

Tags: pointers, memory, fortran

I know that a C pointer is "a variable that holds an address." What about Fortran pointers? Fortran pointers can either be allocated by pointing them to a target or by using the allocate statement. Which is the memory usage of the pointer in both cases? Lets say that I have a pointer:

`pb => b(101:200)`

is it correct to say that pb is only taking 32 bit of memory (if compiled on a 32 bit executable) for storing the address of b(101) and other 32 bit to store the number of elements (100)? 
And If I have:

`pb => b(5,1:10)`

I guess also the stride has to be stored, so the pointer takes 3*32 bits total, is it correct?
But when I allocate a Pointer with:

`Allocate(pb(1:100))`

am I actually reserving 100 memory locations for that pointer? Is here that I am confused. Can anybody clarify?

thanks
Alberto

Answer (score 1):

A fortran array in general (not only a pointer) may be associated to a descriptor containing the address (32 or 64 bits), the lower and upper bounds and the strides. Such descriptor is often used when passing an array by argument to a procedure waiting for an assumed shape array.

When one allocates directly a variable declared pointer, this pointer is associated together to the descriptor above and its associated array.

From a general point of view, allocating directly a pointer is not advised (but this is sometimes necessary for linked lists for instance). I usually allocate only allocatable arrays, and I use pointers only to point to memory zones already allocated.

Allocatable variables have been designed to never involve memory leaks!

Fortran pointers behave diffently than C pointers. You must understand that a Fortran pointer is in fact an alias of the associated memory it points to (alias instead of pointer would have been a better name).

Comment: Wait so when you do allocate(pointername(1:10000)) do you allocate only the descriptor (address=undefined, lower and upper bounds and the stride=1) or do you actually reserve 10000 location of memory for the pointer?thanks a lot

Comment: And also what do you mean with alias? what is the difference in practice?

Comment: In C you always have a distinction between pointer and target. This is not true in Fortran. Most of the time, the use of the pointer is equivalent to the use of the target. The  only exceptions are the use of functions, or assignments specific to pointers like => (changing the target) or ASSOCIATED (checking the state of the pointer).

Comment: About allocate(pointername(1:10000)), you just allocate 10000 values in the memory and the pointer points to that memory. You don't allocate any descriptor : this is already done when declaring the pointer at the top of the procedure (if it is a local variable), like in C. But the Fortran pointer is just complicated than the C pointer and its memory size depends on its declaration (pointers to scalar, vector or matrix differ and cannot be mixted).

Comment: So when you do allocate(pointername(1:10000)) you reserve 10000 locations of memory for the pointer, while when you do pb => b(1:10000) you just reserve a few for the descriptor but you dont allocate other 10000 locations beside the ones already reserved for b, right?

Comment: Right. => never allocates memory

Comment: Those are some important remarks for people used to C pointers that you make in the comments. Thanks. Might be worth updating the answer, even though it is quite old...